# SQLite FTS4 in Android returns zero (0) results while DB Browser returns 400+

Tags: android, sqlite

Here's how I created the FTS table:

```
CREATE virtual TABLE IF NOT EXISTS translationsfts using fts4(verse, surahnbr, versenbr, translator);INSERT INTO translationsfts
SELECT verse, 
       surahnbr, 
       versenbr, 
       translator 
FROM   translations 
JOIN   translators 
ON     translatorid = translators._id;
```

And here's how I query for the data:

```
SELECT DISTINCT verse, 
                surahnbr, 
                versenbr, 
                translator 
FROM            ( 
                       SELECT verse, 
                              surahnbr, 
                              versenbr, 
                              translator, 
                              1 AS rank 
                       FROM   translationsfts 
                       WHERE  verse match '"wherever* you*"' 
                       UNION ALL 
                       SELECT   verse, 
                                surahnbr, 
                                versenbr, 
                                translator, 
                                2 AS rank 
                       FROM     translationsfts 
                       WHERE    verse match 'wherever* you*' 
                       ORDER BY rank, 
                                surahnbr, 
                                versenbr)
```

The problem is, in my app, the query returns 0 results (cursor count is zero). But when I debugged the app and manually extracted the query (which is the second query above), and then input it in [DB Browser for SQLite](http://sqlitebrowser.org/), it returns 400+ results. What's wrong with the Android?

Comment: Probably different SQLite version.

Comment: @CL. I've just tested the following: SELECT * FROM TranslationsFTS, but it still results to 0. I think it's the way FTS table is created. Android is not inserting the data properly. Do you know any solution to this?

Comment: Then it's a problem with the code that creates and fills the table.

Comment: It's the first query above. Do you see any problem in that query? Scroll to the right and there's an 'insert into'. Also, this works in the DB Browser but not in the Android.

Comment: A statement is not a query, and it's incomplete. Show the code that executes those statements.

Comment: It's the exact code except that I'm inserting it inside myDb.execSQL("Query here") for the first query. While the second, I put it inside rawQuery method.

Comment: Edit your question to show the *actual* code.

Comment: @CL. I separated the queries for creating the FTS and the INSERT INTO statement and it worked (ie., I used separate execSQL for the two). But do you know why is this happening?